# Trying to read metadata from mp3 file but get MetadataExtractor.ImageProcessingException: MPEG-2.5 not supported

Tags: .net, metadata-extractor

I am using .net version of metadata extractor.  According to docs it supports mp3 files but when I try to extract from an mp3 file using Mp3MetadataReader.ReadMetadata I get exception:

MetadataExtractor.ImageProcessingException: MPEG-2.5 not supported.

I've tried a few different mp3 files.

Should this work and if so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MPEG 2.5 is not currently supported, and the scarce information I could find about it online suggests it's a proprietary format.

Where are you sourcing these files from?

This request is being tracked in https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/issues/285. If you can share a file on that issue it'd be helpful.